# How can I fix this mistake?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I ended up deleting every application from a folder by mistake.
Was going to delete one particular file, but hit enter before typing completely.
Ended up entering this line and didn't realise what I did until it was too late:

sudo rm -r /usr/share/applications

I'm new to Ubuntu, and my laptop is not on dual boot.

I tried to restore the files using different methods, but failed to do so.

Now, I can't login to my laptop directly. Login is stuck in a loop and I'm unable to do so via the virtual console either (incorrect login). 
The following messages pop-up on the virtual console:

[Here's an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7YAq.png)

I logged-in via Ubuntu (Unity). I use Ubuntu(Gnome) usually.
No data has been lost.

I still can't open any files and external devices (like a USB) won't open. Most of the applications are missing. I still have nautilus.

How can I fix this?

Comment: This is probably out of your depth, as  its an advanced topic and you need to be fluent on the command line. If you press crtl-alt-f1 (or any crtl-alt -f* key) do you get a text login prompt? The steps are to get a bash shell, mount block devices as appropriate, get an internet connection, change the root, reinstall relevant missing packages. If you can login with crtl-alt-f* you can likely jump to user1686 answer

Answer (score 0):

Like Windows, command line tools to remove files (in Linux's case, the `rm` command) doesn't copy stuff to a recycle bin.  It really deletes it.

Linux also inherits the UNIX legacy which assumes you know what you're doing and therefore doesn't ask confirmation for many things, especially core commands like `rm`.

You should back up your data and reinstall Ubuntu.  There won't be an easy way to undelete files that's faster than reinstalling.

In the future, consider using an `ls -R` command to see what files are affected before committing with an `rm -r`.

Comment: How do I reinstall Ubuntu when I'm unable to open any USB drive?

Comment: Is it possible without that?

Comment: You'll have to download the ubuntu image on a different computer and then put it on the usb drive

Answer (score 0):

Many of the symptoms you've listed have nothing to do with this directory. The virtual-console login process actually does not use it at all, and those startup messages inform you about a connection issue with some internal PCIe device (run `lspci` to find out which), and most likely they've been there and in `dmesg` for ages.

The `/usr/share/applications` directory normally doesn't contain the applications themselves, only .desktop files which act as "shortcuts" (similar to Start Menu on Windows). The easiest way to bring them back is to reinstall the affected packages – see this [Unix.SE thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/304120/how-to-recover-a-deleted-folder-full-of-files-managed-by-dpkg) for possible commands to use.

```
packages=$(dpkg -S /usr/share/applications | sed "s/: .*//; s/, / /g")

sudo apt-get install --reinstall $packages
```